# avlancheimagine bundle not generating images

Tags: php, image, symfony, resize, thumbnails

I have just installed AvalancheImagineBundle in Symfony

and I am trying to convert Image to Thumbnail but its not working..

```
<img  src="{{'/hrms/web/uploads/profileimage/8999226bcc8341dc7e076eb09226f8521bbac106.jpeg'|apply_filter('my_thumb')}} " />
```

Here is my config file ..

avalanche_imagine:

```
filters:
    my_thumb:
        type:    thumbnail
        options: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }
```

routing file as follows..

```
_imagine:
    resource: .
    type:     imagine
```

I am getting this as HTML

```
<img src="/hrms/web/app_dev.php/media/cache/my_thumb/hrms/web/uploads/profileimage/8999226bcc8341dc7e076eb09226f8521bbac106.jpeg }}">
```

I have not created any folders is it necessary..?
help me..

If I remove hrms/web/ from image url it is working..

Answer (score 0):

hello i use AvalancheImagineBundle

my config and route is same as you but i get my img src in another way and you haven't to create any folder ex :

config :

```
avalanche_imagine:
    filters:
        my_big_banner:
            type:    relative_resize
            options: { widen: 940, format: jpg, quality: 100  }
```

routing :

```
_imagine:
    resource: .
    type:     imagine
```

HTML :

```
<img id="big-bannerImgShow" style="background-image: url('{{ (entity.evenImage.webPath) | apply_filter('my_big_banner')}}')">
```

i hope this help you